# "I can't write on file"

Tags: errors

[image: .]

I don't get this mistake. This occured from nowhere. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You probably have lab reprt2.pdf open in acrobat or some other viewer that locks the file. You need to close the file in acrobat, or use a different viewer that allows the pdf to be regenerated while viewing.

Comment: Is the pdf file is currently open when you try to compile a new pdf file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your question doesn't give us nearly enough information to answer it.  We don't know what TeX distribution you're using, what your underlying operating system might be, what pdf viewer you're using...  Please provide as much  information about your setup as you can, so you can help us help you.

Comment: Close the pdf and recompile your files. This occurs in Windows however, in Mac you don't have to close the pdf however you need to close it to see the modifications though.

Comment: I don't like to ask, but would it not have been possible to at least use Print Screen? Ideally those messages could be copy and pasted, or, in extremis, retyped - which would help other people searching for similar problems but would also make things easier for us! Fortunately, this picture seems to have been enough this time, but in general, you'll find that the better the question, the better the answers!

Answer (score 2):

The file is probably open in another program. Close the file and try it again.